# How to display a image when there is no internet connection (web view)

Tags: xcode

I have a web view based program I was just testing. How do you display a image when there is no internet connection?

I have a basic webview

```
    //
//  XYZViewController.m
//  Phantomore
//
//  Created by Kevin Jin on 5/15/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Kevin Jin. All rights reserved.
//

#import "XYZViewController.h"

@interface XYZViewController ()

@end

@implementation XYZViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *fullURL = @"http://www.phantomore.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Thats it,I just want to know what I have to do to have it displaying a image when tehre is no internet connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just simplified mamnun answer([Get Reachability here](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)).

You can use this method after you have implemented the reachability class

```
- (BOOL)isConnectedToInternet
{
    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus networkStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    return !(networkStatus == NotReachable);
}
```

In any of your class

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if([self isConnectedToInternet]){
       //Hide your imageview
       NSString *fullURL = @"http://www.phantomore.com";
       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
       NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
       [_viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
    }
   else{
       // Hide your webview
       // Show your imageview
       // Do not forget to import reachability class on top
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two way of doing it.

1. Before even performing the url request, check if internet connection is available. Use [Apple provided Reachability classes](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) or better yet use the [open-source version](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability). If internet is available load the request. If not add an UIImageView with your preferred UIImage as a subview of the webview. You can do something like this:

   ```
   //inside @interface
   @property(nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;

   //inside -(void)viewDidLoad
   self.imageView = [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"as.as"];
   Reachability* reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];
   reach.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach) {
       // load request
   NSString *fullURL = @"http://www.phantomore.com";
       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
       NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
       [_viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
   };

   reach.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach) {
       //show imageview
       [_viewWeb addSubView:self.imageView];
   };
   [reach startNotifier];
   ```
2. Implement [UIWebView delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). In the – webView:didFailLoadWithError: method, check the error. If the error is caused by no internet connection, add the imageview(same as before).